# How to download a video file from amazon s3 to specific folder using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a video file from S3 account.It is niether giving me an error nor I am able to see the file downloaded means I am not getting the location of file.I have a doubt that is my file is getting downloaded.Pls give a solution on this.Thanks in advance here is my code:

```
System.out.println("Downloading an object");
        S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
        System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
         object.getObjectContent();
    }catch(AmazonServiceException ex){
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ex.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ex.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ex.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ex.getRequestId());
    }catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object.getObjectContent() gives the stream of data from the HTTP connection, is there any exception reading from the stream? you can also try s3.getObjectAsString()